# How do I make a pure css auto slider that is responsive? (no JavaScript)

Tags: html, css, slider, slideshow, css-animations

I have a fully functional auto slider (picture show) that I adapted from here:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/

However it is not responsive. In my case, the divs around the image ('mask', 'slider', 'content-slider', etc.)  don't shrink with the image. The image shrinks fine. I'm looking for a css solution.

My thought is (after a lot of searching) I just convert everything to percentages instead of pixels, but that doesn't seem to be working for me. For example (as adapted from online search results) 325px would be 100%, 0px would be 0%, and -325px would be -100% through out the style.css and animation.css, but as mentioned, that doesn't work. The images should slide vertically and fade out (opacity).

I'm stumped.

Here is the code I think you need....

Here is my html:

```
<html lang="en"><head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="content-slider">
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="mask">
            <ul>
            <li id="first" class="firstanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="slider-img" src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="Cougar">
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <a href="#" class="slider-h1-a">
            <h1><span style="color: red">●</span> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1>
             </a>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="second" class="secondanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="slider-img" src="images/img_2.jpg" alt="Lions">
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <a href="#" class="slider-h1-a">
            <h1><span style="color: red">●</span> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1>
             </a>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="third" class="thirdanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="slider-img" src="images/img_3.jpg" alt="Snowalker">
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <a href="#" class="slider-h1-a">
            <h1><span style="color: red">●</span> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1>
             </a>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="fourth" class="fourthanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="slider-img" src="images/img_4.jpg" alt="Howling">
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <a href="#" class="slider-h1-a">
            <h1><span style="color: red">●</span> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="fifth" class="fifthanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="slider-img" src="images/img_5.jpg" alt="Sunbathing">
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <a href="#" class="slider-h1-a">
            <h1><span style="color: red">●</span>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

Here is my style.css:

```
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

/* CONTENT SLIDER */
#content-slider {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
/* SLIDER */
#slider {
    background: #e5e8ea;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
}
#mask {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:320px;
}
#slider ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#slider li {
    width:100%;
    height:320px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-325px;
    list-style:none;
}
#slider li.firstanimation {
    -moz-animation:cycle 25s linear infinite;   
    -webkit-animation:cycle 25s linear infinite;    
    animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;   
}
#slider li.secondanimation {
    -moz-animation:cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:cycletwo 25s linear infinite; 
    animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;    
}
#slider li.thirdanimation {
    -moz-animation:cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
    animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;      
}
#slider li.fourthanimation {
    -moz-animation:cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:cyclefour 25s linear infinite;        
    animation: cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
}
#slider li.fifthanimation {
    -moz-animation:cyclefive 25s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:cyclefive 25s linear infinite;    
    animation: cyclefive 25s linear infinite;   
}
```

Here is my animation.css (webkit keyframes only for the example):

```
@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    4%  { top:0px; }
    16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    20% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    21% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    50% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    92% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    96% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }

}
@-webkit-keyframes cycletwo {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    16% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    20% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    24% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    36% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    40% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    41% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }  
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclethree {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    36% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    40% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    44% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    56% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    60% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    61% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclefour {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    56% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    60% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    64% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    76% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    80% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    81% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclefive {
    0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    76% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    80% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    84% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    96% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    100%{ top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
}
```

Comment: I am also looking for that answer! @mountainclimber, did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Yes, I did. I ended up searching the internet and putting together those ideas. Sorry, my "solution" isn't worthy of posting for others. Best of luck!

Comment: Well then I gave up the pure CSS slideshow (I spent too much time on it) andI will go with a js slideshow. That one is really great and easy to set up! http://themarklee.com/2014/10/05/better-simple-slideshow/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure CSS3 slideshow repeats the last 4 slides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571533/pure-css3-slideshow-repeats-the-last-4-slides)