# Pure CSS3 slideshow repeats the last 4 slides?

Tags: html, css

I found a script, namely: "[Pure CSS / CSS3 Slideshow with Image Panning and zooming Effect](http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-css3-slideshow-with-image-panning-and-zooming-effect/)".

The problem with this it that it repeats the last 4 slides. Could someone tell me why and how to resolve this problem?

[My first fiddle, demonstrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/iorgu/0Lwwj7yo/).

[My second one, proving the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/iorgu/0Lwwj7yo/1/).

The HTML:

```
<div class="pic-wrapper lejatszokep">
    <figure class="pic-1"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-2"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-3"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-4"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-5"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-6"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-7"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-8"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-9"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-10"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-11"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-12"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-13"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-14"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-15"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-16"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-17"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-18"></figure>
    <figure class="pic-19"></figure>
</div>
```

The CSS3:

```
    .pic-wrapper {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 259px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    figure {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 258px;
      height: 200px;
      opacity: 0;
      /*animation*/

      animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite;
      -o-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite;
      -webkit-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite;

/*suggestion by marczking to make the code shorter: */

      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .pic-1 {
        opacity:1;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_01.jpg) no-repeat center center;

    }
    .pic-2 {
      animation-delay: 6s;
      -o-animation-delay: 6s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 6s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_02.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-3 {
      animation-delay: 12s;
      -o-animation-delay: 12s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 12s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_03.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-4 {
      animation-delay: 18s;
      -o-animation-delay: 18s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 18s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_04.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-5 {
      animation-delay: 24s;
      -o-animation-delay: 24s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 24s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_05.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-6 {
      animation-delay: 30s;
      -o-animation-delay: 30s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 30s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_06.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-7 {
      animation-delay: 36s;
      -o-animation-delay: 36s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 36s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_07.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-8 {
      animation-delay: 42s;
      -o-animation-delay: 42s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 42s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 42s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_08.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-9 {
      animation-delay: 48s;
      -o-animation-delay: 48s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 48s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 48s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_09.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-10 {
      animation-delay: 54s;
      -o-animation-delay: 54s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 54s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 54s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_10.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-11 {
      animation-delay: 60s;
      -o-animation-delay: 60s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 60s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_11.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-12 {
      animation-delay: 66s;
      -o-animation-delay: 66s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 66s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 66s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_12.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-13 {
      animation-delay: 72s;
      -o-animation-delay: 72s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 72s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 72s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_13.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-14 {
      animation-delay: 78s;
      -o-animation-delay: 78s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 78s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 78s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_14.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-15 {
      animation-delay: 84s;
      -o-animation-delay: 84s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 84s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 84s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_15.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-16 {
      animation-delay: 90s;
      -o-animation-delay: 90s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 90s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 90s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_16.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-17 {
      animation-delay: 96s;
      -o-animation-delay: 96s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 96s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 96s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_17.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-18 {
      animation-delay: 102s;
      -o-animation-delay: 102s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 102s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 102s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_18.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    .pic-19 {
      animation-delay: 108s;
      -o-animation-delay: 108s;
      -moz--animation-delay: 108s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 108s;
      background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_19.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    }
    /* keyframes*/

    @keyframes slideShow {  
     0% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform:scale(1);
     -ms-transform:scale(1);
    }
     5% {
     opacity: 1
    }
     25% {
     opacity: 1;
    }
     30% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform:scale(1.1);
     -ms-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
     100% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform:scale(1);
     -ms-transformm:scale(1);
    }
    }
     @-o-keyframes 
    slideShow {  0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform:scale(1);
    }
     5% {
     opacity: 1
    }
     25% {
     opacity: 1;
    }
     30% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
     100% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transformm:scale(1);
    }
    }
     @-moz-keyframes 
    slideShow {  0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform:scale(1);
    }
     5% {
     opacity: 1
    }
     25% {
     opacity: 1;
    }
     30% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
     100% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transformm:scale(1);
    }
    }
     @-webkit-keyframes 
    slideShow {  0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    }
     5% {
     opacity: 1
    }
     25% {
     opacity: 1;
    }
     30% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
     100% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transformm:scale(1);
    }
    }
```

```css
 .pic-wrapper {
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 259px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 figure {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 258px;
   height: 200px;
   opacity: 0;
   /*animation*/
   animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite;
   -o-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite;
   /*suggestion by marczking to make the code shorter: */
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
 }
 .pic-1 {
   opacity: 1;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_01.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-2 {
   animation-delay: 6s;
   -o-animation-delay: 6s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 6s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_02.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-3 {
   animation-delay: 12s;
   -o-animation-delay: 12s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 12s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_03.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-4 {
   animation-delay: 18s;
   -o-animation-delay: 18s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 18s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_04.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-5 {
   animation-delay: 24s;
   -o-animation-delay: 24s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 24s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_05.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-6 {
   animation-delay: 30s;
   -o-animation-delay: 30s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 30s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_06.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-7 {
   animation-delay: 36s;
   -o-animation-delay: 36s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 36s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_07.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-8 {
   animation-delay: 42s;
   -o-animation-delay: 42s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 42s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 42s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_08.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-9 {
   animation-delay: 48s;
   -o-animation-delay: 48s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 48s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 48s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_09.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-10 {
   animation-delay: 54s;
   -o-animation-delay: 54s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 54s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 54s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_10.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-11 {
   animation-delay: 60s;
   -o-animation-delay: 60s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 60s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_11.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-12 {
   animation-delay: 66s;
   -o-animation-delay: 66s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 66s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 66s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_12.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-13 {
   animation-delay: 72s;
   -o-animation-delay: 72s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 72s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 72s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_13.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-14 {
   animation-delay: 78s;
   -o-animation-delay: 78s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 78s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 78s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_14.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-15 {
   animation-delay: 84s;
   -o-animation-delay: 84s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 84s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 84s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_15.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-16 {
   animation-delay: 90s;
   -o-animation-delay: 90s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 90s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 90s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_16.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-17 {
   animation-delay: 96s;
   -o-animation-delay: 96s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 96s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 96s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_17.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-18 {
   animation-delay: 102s;
   -o-animation-delay: 102s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 102s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 102s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_18.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 .pic-19 {
   animation-delay: 108s;
   -o-animation-delay: 108s;
   -moz--animation-delay: 108s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 108s;
   background: url(http://88t.eu/Pictures/sh/1/intr_19.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 }
 /* keyframes*/
 @keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: scale(1);
     -ms-transform: scale(1);
   }
   5% {
     opacity: 1
   }
   25% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   30% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: scale(1.1);
     -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: scale(1);
     -ms-transformm: scale(1);
   }
 }
 @-o-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform: scale(1);
   }
   5% {
     opacity: 1
   }
   25% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   30% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transformm: scale(1);
   }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(1);
   }
   5% {
     opacity: 1
   }
   25% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   30% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transformm: scale(1);
   }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   }
   5% {
     opacity: 1
   }
   25% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   30% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transformm: scale(1);
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="pic-wrapper lejatszokep">
  <figure class="pic-1"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-2"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-3"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-4"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-5"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-6"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-7"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-8"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-9"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-10"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-11"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-12"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-13"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-14"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-15"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-16"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-17"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-18"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-19"></figure>
</div>
```

Comment: i think it has to do with your `animation-duration` property but i'm not sure

Comment: @cocoa It somehow makes sense - what you say, but then the animation gets slower or faster. Is there some-kind of reference how to use this kind of script?

Comment: check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: this has nothing to do with you issue, but you could define f.ex. `background-size` once for your `figure` instead of for each `pic-x`. Just to keep your CSS a bit shorter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the time set for your `animation`. When i changed the time to 114s it cycled throught all images.

If you need to make it faster or slower you will have to go through and adjust the `animation` on the `figure` element and the `animation-delay` manually on each `.pic-x` element.

Answer (score 1):

This code is way too long, too many classes, unpractical to maintain and much unnecessary Css.
I did not check why this does not work properly, it will be the set timing.
Do it like this instead, it's much less code and fully responsive, and you can easily add and remove pics:

```
div#slider figure {
position: relative;
width: 800%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 0;
text-align: left;
-webkit-animation: 28s bro infinite;  
animation: 28s slidy infinite; 
}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/wKxgpz